# Validation of file for ASP.Net Upload to server Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, web, download

Im working with a co-worker on Visual Studio, using the file upload control to allow the user to upload a file to the server, however I can't seem to find a way to validate the file before allowing the upload.

For example I would like to stop them if they are trying to upload a file that is not relevant to their problem.

I am just starting on the asp.net side of things myself, so any shove in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you decide if the file is relevant to their problem?

Comment: @nunespascal Maybe he's asking us how to write an AI?

Comment: I plan to reference the information they report in the previous form against whatever information I can gather from the file download control. Specifically I wanted to steer them away from .exe or .pdf, mostly the file type is what concerns me. @Andrew Thanks for the edits.

Comment: "File type" and "File extension" are not related, necessarily, by the way. But if you just want to check the file extension, take it from the file name passed in by the control.

Comment: The file extension is not indicative of the file type? I believe the suggested above is what I am having trouble accomplishing. There has to be something of the stream that indicates a file apart from another. Then again gmail can't distinguish a zip from a piz if the name is changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default asp.net fileupload control does not provide this check.

You can use a RegularExpressionValidator to validate the extension.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" 
     ValidationExpression="^.*\.(png|PNG)$" runat="server" />
```

The html `accept` attribute can come handy, but since this is not natively supported, you will have to add it yourself.

```
<!-- Match all image files (image/*) and files with the extension ".someext" -->
<input type="file" accept=".someext,image/*">
```

Comment: Thank you, for your detailed direction and examples.